# Php Error - Not sure where it is coming from or what it means?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$filename="vast/Vastopolis_Map.png";
$image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);

// get properties of the image as an array $size
// $size[0] is the width of the image in pixel
// $size[1] is the height

$size = getimagesize($filename);
$width = $size[0];
$height = $size[1];

// Set the color (red)
$ink_color = imagecolorallocatealpha ($image, 244, 1, 1, 100);
// Set line thickness if needed
// imagesetthickness($image, 5);

// get GPS locations where text meets selection criteria
// Connect to MySQL, assume the database is called vast
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vast';
$username = '###';
$passwd = '###';

$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd);

// Select text that mentions flu or fever
// Option 1: text like '%flu%' or text like '%fever%'
// Option 2: text regexp 'flu|fever'
$sql = "SELECT Location, Text FROM blogs WHERE Text LIKE '%flu%' '";
$results = $db->query($sql);

// Linear transformation to match the coordinates on the map
// The upper left corner of the map: 42.3017, 93.5673
// The lower right corner of the map: 42.1609, 93.1923
$minX = 42.3017;
$maxX = 42.1609;

$minY = 93.5673;
$maxY = 93.1923;
// Linear transformation. What does it do?
$a = $width/($maxX-$minX);
$b = -$minX*$a;

$c = $height/($maxY-$minY);
$d = -$minY*$c;

// Set the color of the markers - red
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha ($image, 250, 10, 10, 50);

// plot each location returned from the query to the database
foreach ($results as $row) {
$location = $row[0];
$pos = preg_split("/\s+/", $location); // why?
$X = $pos[0];
$Y = $pos[1];
$x = $a*$X + $b;
$y = $c*$Y + $d;
imagefilledellipse($image, $x, $y, 10, 10, $color);
}
// serve the image to the client
header ("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);

?>
```

it is throwing this disgusting error, anyone??

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 51

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by  on line 61
‰PNG  IHDR` ]×ý{~÷PLTEôú ûûûèæÙãÒìæÓÔÖçæËäÎÑÐêÒÐÑæï®âæšìÎ­éÂšÈê³ØâšËÔ¯ËËä¼åæ·ËÐ·æË¬ÏÃÆæ®­ã¸‘ä æŽÏ®¯Ð­‰Ç—¬Æ‘Œºãó»ãÒ·Èí±ÒÆË÷˜ÈÃ¹ä«·âš®Ì­ªÌ‘›Â±šÄŠ¨Ï­­®­²®‹®°Œ’´§¬Ž’§‹‹ÄÅyä­yæ€}ò‘IÌ¥yÃµYÄ˜pÃ[ùƒ+Ê8®Â{¬¬m¤¥Z±i®„X‰¬q™¢Y‹“nŽP¨¢;¤‚<‘ >„ˆ;„å}Är¦É}ƒ{Í¤|¤§v¦\¡©VŒ–v¤mX¨…\…‘2‡çppð`^ç\bêPQÔpqÊnVÒ]bÔQRíy%þjë@>ìZÌr'ÒiØA>ÍX ð=CÔ>Bë34ñ!þ"ý   Õ67Å:Ì§rn¥yQ¢\f«RSnm‘mLŠYo†YL£v;´e«\+±XŽf:ƒm†Y5ŒT®=F†2m„:L‚m­/1®'¾‰2+‚'Ž ƒ rÀúT¤ázª¤|¢{ˆ¢s“‰P¥¥U¨‰O‡¯[ˆƒ“þ-ƒ¸-‘¶……z£ix¡[qllŽT[¡n_ C[ƒrZ…Lxƒ:iƒU…:Sƒ2‡m4„W‚w…N2ƒg`Õsk³qsˆdZ´tU†Jx©[iƒUK±UMŽC;Ùj0‡d‡E9¬H8\ {È&mŸ$á3)®3'—&®&”­‘mmpltPmRnqQNVpmToLSUkOONqn6~jrO0kHNm5Z}NT0NNfde:.f:p#~R4/N0L-C8kf-lG8Kf4PN~~lDJ~GH*g7&~2R-/Md8sU-G63c25M#}5Jtéã°ER¶ÁSÆ3tŸwC×ëx<ñ“ÏÉ¼øÇvæßžpvü0#V>¶[û]oGÿÏÓc{ÚhEõlóï‡1g çFû|‡Úà®–\¿^o×ö~mÏãO?ÿô`Åè^<ë®òe{öØÓ>°ý~×§ íøszŠèê¾ªnz¤>â<äø°^÷:Ì¶óu;ö]…:þtÜöUÍ’«6QvKn|@ÉÖL¸ëoêk8|`ítSû9«°\Ú³Ï'BÆ•¥5ÚªãŽ¨_tû «¬tøíúív½¶;ÿÝow>»À›íÃÃÑÊÓuµýòðªª¶Gœ€Õvª?”è”;Ee§`þm{az`Ÿ­åzÄyí1"‹žÝÑÎ÷ÓqTÓXÕvÖKí÷
```

Not sure if this is a db error, or something with php. Completely lost why its doing this or what its talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an stray ' in your query, which makes it invalid

```
$sql = "SELECT Location, Text FROM blogs WHERE Text LIKE '%flu%' '";
```

should be

```
$sql = "SELECT Location, Text FROM blogs WHERE Text LIKE '%flu%'";
```

A malformed query will make `$results` an error code instead of an array of results. Since there are no results in `$results`, you can't use `foreach` on it without errors, as `foreach` can only be used on arrays.

Since the `foreach` causes an error, which prints and send to the user, it will generate the "headers already sent" error. Which the cause, and the effect will be solved too.

Answer (score 2):

It means your `$db->query($sql);` returned an empty result set.

Answer (score 1):

When the warning is printed , it sends the header. Stop the foreach warning the error would go away.

Answer (score 1):

$results is not an array.  You can ensure that it's the right type by using var_dump or is_array.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try `print_r($db->errorInfo());` to get more info about a possible mysql error.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about PDO, but I can tell that $results is [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php), not an array.

I think you may use some method like [fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)... not foreach...